# useform display iframe after submit

Tags: reactjs, iframe, breeze, use-form

I use Breeze with useForm and if I use post method, it return result in iframe. Look at my example

```
    const { data, setData, post, processing, errors } = useForm({
        name: '',
        email: ''
    });
    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        post(route('store'));
    };
//...
```

After submit it display iframe. It should be usefull if I have an error. In Breeze's example after submit controller's method redirect but I won't do that. I want to display toast. How can I disable this iframe?

@Edit

```
RegisterUserController
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        // return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

Register.js

```
export default function Register() {
    const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password_confirmation: '',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            reset('password', 'password_confirmation');
        };
    }, []);

    const onHandleChange = (event) => {
        setData(event.target.name, event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value);
    };

    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        post(route('register'));
    };

    return (
        <Guest>
            <Head title="Register" />

            <ValidationErrors errors={errors} />

            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <div>
                    <Label forInput="name" value="Name" />

                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        value={data.name}
                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                        autoComplete="name"
                        isFocused={true}
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                        required
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4">
                    <Label forInput="email" value="Email" />

                    <Input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        value={data.email}
                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                        autoComplete="username"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                        required
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4">
                    <Label forInput="password" value="Password" />

                    <Input
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={data.password}
                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                        autoComplete="new-password"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                        required
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4">
                    <Label forInput="password_confirmation" value="Confirm Password" />

                    <Input
                        type="password"
                        name="password_confirmation"
                        value={data.password_confirmation}
                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                        required
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                    <Link href={route('login')} className="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900">
                        Already registered?
                    </Link>

                    <Button className="ml-4" processing={processing}>
                        Register
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </Guest>
    );
```

Comment: Please link to the Breeze example that you mentioned.

Comment: Look at my post.